# How to properly map [ server.com:port ] to [ server.com/param ] for node.js app?

Tags: node.js, apache, mod-rewrite, socket.io, proxypass

I'm relatively new to Node.js and have been trying to solve this problem quite some time.

So, basically I want to map my **server.com/chat** to **server.com:9999**.
Tried to accomplish this using *ProxyPass* and *ProxyPassReverse* in my apache confs but I guess node server itself is having problem serving the socket.io file with a new url.

Here are the screens

## server.com:9999

[image: server.com:9999]

## server.com/chat

[image: server.com/chat]

## config file

[image: config]

Any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT:

## New screen, problem with a handshake

[image: handshake problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In last two images, I can see you did not proxy for /socket.io route. You should proxy for /socket.io/ route as well

```
ProxyPass /socket.io http://server.com:9999
ProxyPassReverse /socket.io http://server.com:9999
```

I would like to recommend to use `RewriteCond` for websocket used by socket.io and you may like to have a look https://serverfault.com/questions/616370/configuring-apache-2-4-mod-proxy-wstunnel-for-socket-io-1-0/623027#623027

Comment: Thanks for great tip but problem remains still.. It seems to be unable to make a handshake. Messaging works well but connection persists no matter the tab closed. http://i.stack.imgur.com/6WJhh.jpg

I have tried rewritecond you linked me but apache throwed a syntax error upon restart.

Comment: Have you added websocket proxy `ws://server.com:9999` ? Please make sure you have enabled `apache proxy_wstunnel` module as well.

Comment: Thanks for directives! You are awesome!
`a2enmod proxy_wstunnel` fixed the issue.